# Abandoned multi-part uploads to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-java-sdk

We are uploading data to Azure Blob Storage using Microsoft's Java client library. First we create a blob for uploading:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = client.getContainerReference(containerName);
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(nativePath);
```

Each part to be uploaded is done with code like this:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(part.path.toFile())) {
  String blockId = String.format("%05d", part.index);
  String blockIdEncoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(blockId.getBytes());
  blob.uploadBlock(blockIdEncoded, inputStream, part.size);
}
```

at the end, all of the parts are stitched together into a blob using:

```
blob.commitBlockList(blockList);
```

What happens if this process is abandoned (due to termination or logic error) before the commitBlockList() is called?  Do the parts leak?  Are they garbage collected eventually?  Can I see them somewhere on the Azure portal?

How should I terminate this process gracefully so that all of the uploaded-but-unused parts are deleted?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `Do the parts leak?`. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens if this process is abandoned (due to termination or logic
> error) before the commitBlockList() is called?

Any blocks you upload and not committed remain in Azure Storage for a period of 7 days.

> Are they garbage collected eventually?

Yes, after 7 days.

> Can I see them somewhere on the Azure portal?

No. You cannot see these blocks in Azure portal. However you can get the list of blocks for blob by calling [`Get Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-block-list) REST API operation (or equivalent SDK operation).

> How should I terminate this process gracefully so that all of the
> uploaded parts are deleted?

Currently there's no way for you to delete the uncommitted blocks. One way to solve this problem is to upload a zero byte blob with the same name and delete that blob. When you upload a blob with the same name, the existing blocks will be deleted.

You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block#remarks.

Comment: awesome answer!

Comment: DO you know if this same garbage collection is enabled for ADL gen2?

Comment: Considering ADLS Gen2 is built on top of blob storage, I am assuming that the answer is applicable there as well.